# Populate data using another collection array in mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

My database Collections:

namelists:

```
{
    "_id": {
        "$oid": "5bd587adfb6fc074abb12cb2"
    },
    "name": "name 1",
    "year": "3",
    "id": "101"
}
,
{
    "_id": {
        "$oid": "5bd587cffb6fc074abb12cb8"
    },
    "name": "name 2",
    "year": "4",
    "id": "102"
},
{
    "_id": {
        "$oid": "5bd587e9fb6fc074abb12cbe"
    },
    "name": "name 3",
    "year": "2",
    "id": "103"
}
```

winners:

```
{
    "_id": {
        "$oid": "5bd58921fb6fc074abb12ce8"
    },
    "id": "301",
    "winner": [
        "101",
        "102"
    ]
}
```

I need module which traverse the array(id field) in the winner collection and find the data in namelist collection that matches(id field in namelist collection) the array(id) in the winner collection.

```
//I have two Schema namelist and winner

var Schema = mongoose.Schema;

var namelist = new Schema({
  _id: mongoose.Schema.ObjectId,
  id: String,
  name: String, 
  year: String
},
  {
  strict: false
});
var Namelist = mongoose.model('namelist', namelist);

var winner = new Schema({
  _id: mongoose.Schema.ObjectId,
  id: String,
  winner:[ String ]
},
  {
  strict: false
});
var Winner = mongoose.model('winner', winner);

//populate part

Namlist.find({ id: id }).
  populate('winner').
  exec(function (err, data) {
    if (err) return handleError(err);
    console.log(data);

  });
```

**I need module which traverse the array(id filed) in the winner collection and find the data in namelist collection that matches(id field in namelist collection) the array(id) in the winner collection.**

Expected Output

```
{
    "_id": {
        "$oid": "5bd587adfb6fc074abb12cb2"
    },
    "name": "name 1",
    "year": "3",
    "id": "101"
}
,
{
    "_id": {
        "$oid": "5bd587cffb6fc074abb12cb8"
    },
    "name": "name 2",
    "year": "4",
    "id": "102"
}
```

Except id:103 it should display other data using the winner collection

Thanks in Advance

Comment: `Namlist.find({ id: id })` - what's the value of  `id` as a parameter in this case ?

Comment: the id from winner array in winner collection @mickl

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To use `.populate()` in mongoose you need to define a reference between entities using `ref` as the documentation states ([here](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html)). In this case you can use regular [$lookup](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/) to merge the data from both collections and then you can [$unwind](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/index.html) and [$replaceRoot](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/replaceRoot/index.html) to get items from `namelists` as a result. Try:

```
let result = await Winner.aggregate([
        { $match: { id: "301" } },
        { $lookup: { from: "namelists", localField: "winner", foreignField: "id", as: "winner"  } },
        { $unwind: "$winner" },
        { $replaceRoot: { newRoot: "$winner" } }
    ]);
console.log(result);
```

or using the old, callback style:

```
Winner.aggregate([
        { $match: { id: "301" } },
        { $lookup: { from: "namelists", localField: "winner", foreignField: "id", as: "winner"  } },
        { $unwind: "$winner" },
        { $replaceRoot: { newRoot: "$winner" } }
    ], function(err, result){
  console.log(result);
});
```

Prints:

```
[ { _id: 5bd587adfb6fc074abb12cb2,
    name: 'name 1',
    year: '3',
    id: '101' },
{ _id: 5bd587cffb6fc074abb12cb8,
    name: 'name 2',
    year: '4',
    id: '102' } ]
```

Comment: SyntaxError: await is only valid in async function

Comment: can you edit the schema as well with ref and achieve it using populate

Comment: @Godwin if your app does not support async and await you can us callbacks, edited my answer

Comment: I think populate is convenient when you reference items by `_id` field, in your case there's no big difference between populate in lookup as you define the relationship using custom field (in my opinion obviously)